# Как найти словосочетание в строке и занести его в другую строчную переменную?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, строки

В переменную `s` из файла считываются строки. Как из этих строк извлечь и записать в другую строчную переменную ,например, все словосочетания, которые содержат: "user: (какое-то имя),". Имя состоит из одного слова, словосочетание ограничивается запятой `,` .

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s; 
ifstream file("file1"); 

int count = 1;
while (getline(file, s)) { 
    cout << "String " << "#" << count << ": " << s << endl; 
    count++;
}
file.close(); 

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: а имя может состоять из  двух слов или словосочетание  ограничивается каким то символом- обо всем об этом нужно известить

Comment: @ARHovsepyan исправил.

Comment: Во вторых вы даже не пытаетесь  решать эту тривиальную задачу. Тут достаточно  использовать std::string::find  с аргументом "user:"..  т.е. найти это слово, а потом записать это слово и  следующее слово тоже. Сделать это, пока не достигнут конец файла.  Решать конечно можно и другими способами, но попытайтесь  хоть как то решать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного изменений в цикле, и получим решение:

```
while (getline(file, s, ',')) {
    size_t pos = s.find("user");
    if (pos == string::npos)
        continue;
    s.erase(s.begin(), s.begin() + pos);
    cout << "String " << "#" << count << ": " << s << endl;
    count++;
}
```

если конечно после всех имен точно есть символ ограничитель ','. Иначе код немного  станет больше или используется другой альгоритм

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.